# Strange control line when opening a file

Tags: terminal

Sometimes (about once/twice a day), when I open a file in vim, I get a strange line containing meta control characters right at the top of the buffer.

[image: strange line]

The line goes away when I refresh the buffer, so it's not really a problem.

I'm just curious to know why it happens. I run vim in a terminal and I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

```
$> vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 06 2019 17:31:41)
Included patches: 1-1453
```

I've used vim on various machines for many years, but my current laptop is the only one where I've seen this happen.

Comment: I think it'll be useful if you could include a copy of your ~/.vimrc and perhaps the list of plugins that you use in ~/.vim/

Comment: Also, which terminal are you using? What is `$TERM` set to in your shell inside that terminal?

Comment: this is most likely a problem of your terminal configuration. Make sure that $TERM is correct. Also you seem to have `termguicolors` set. Make sure your terminal actually understands that.

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark... But try removing `set termguicolors` from your `.vimrc` if you have it. If you're setting `set t_Co=256` (or another value) try removing that too to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I could be wrong but the first CSI sequence (`^[[2;2R`) looks like the reply to a DSR sequence (Device Status Report). I think it reports the cursor position; here row 2, column 2. The second CSI sequence (`^[[>1;5202;0c`) looks like the reply to a Send Device Attributes sequence (`CSI > Pp ; Pv ; Pc ; c`). It's claiming that the terminal type is VT220 (because here `Pp` is 1), and that its firmware/patch version is 5202 (because here `Pv` is 5202).

Comment: The purpose of the first OSC sequence (`^[]10;rgb:0000/0000/0000^G`) is to change the text foreground color, and the last OSC sequence (`^[]11;rgb:e0e0/e0e0/e0e0^G`) changes the text background color.
You can find all of this information on: https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html
I guess some program sends those sequences to get some info about the terminal and to change some of its attributes, but the terminal doesn't understand them. As already said, it's often an issue with `TERM`, or maybe some Vim terminal-related options (`:set termcap`, `:h termcap`).

Comment: {"terminal":"gnome-terminal v3.28.2", "$TERM":"xterm-256color", ":set termguicolors?":"notermguicolors", "set t_Co?":256}

Comment: *my current laptop is the only one where I've seen this happen* Try to find what's different in the environment of your laptop. FWIW, I would start with the Vim plugins. Are there plugins which you use only on your laptop? Can you remember a plugin which you installed in the same time frame where the issue started to appear? If so, try to disable it. Or just bisect all your plugins.

Comment: Did you map escape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2` and I am using gruvbox color scheme (I also have some other vim plugins like syntastic).

After adding `autocmd vimenter * colorscheme gruvbox` in my .vimrc **before** the loading of my plugin manager (pathogen) this went off (I've also removed my previous `colorscheme gruvbox` command from my .vimrc of course).

I guess if you are also using a color scheme and if you replace "gruvbox" by your desired color scheme this might work for you as well.

---

**Notes**

- I got this solution from https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Installation.
- Not sure why this did solve my problem but as stated in the link just above [vim always read .vimrc file first and after that starts to load plugins, so in this case, we use autocmd vimenter to be sure that all plugins are loaded completely and then use gruvbox](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Installation), I guess the color scheme loading needs those setups to be totally finished before being launched in order to work properly.
- [Here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#VimEnter) is the doc on vimenter, for those who are not familiar with this
- This looks strongly related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129631/vim-8-1-garbage-printing-on-screen/62775405#62775405) and [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/cnyrva/first_line_occasionally_has_weird_characters_and/).

Comment: It's been a long time since I last saw this happen, but I have no idea whether I did something to make it go away. Although I don't use gruvbox, I'm going to "accept" your answer for all the details you've added. Thanks.